# catching socket and signal events with pselect

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I'm making a messaging service that needs to use both socket io and shared memory. The routine will be the same regardless of where the input comes from, with the only difference being local messages will be passed via shared memory and non-local messages over a socket. Both events will have to unblock the same pselect call. 
At this point I think the best option might be to send a signal whenever a message is written to shared memory and use it to interrupt a pselect call but I'm not quite sure how this would be done or even if it's the best route.

I'm not used to using signals. what's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: this link may help you  http://www.binarytides.com/server-client-example-c-sockets-linux/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't use pselect or signals. In fact it doesn't even use select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use signals, use `sigqueue` to send them - you can send an integer payload with this, for example an offset into your shared memory.

Make sure to register your signal handler with `sigaction` and use the `sa_sigaction` callback: the `siginfo_t->si_int` member will contain that payload.

In general, I'm not sure I can recommend using this mechanism instead of a unix pipe or eventfd, because I'm not sure whether signal delivery is really tuned for speed as you hope: benchmark to be sure.

---

PS. performance aside, one reason signals feel a bit icky is that you lose the opportunity to have a "well-known" rendezvous like an inet or unix port, and instead have to go looking for a PID. Also, you have to be very careful about masking to make sure the signal is delivered where you want.

PPS. You raise or send a signal - you don't throw it. That's for exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

I would consider using a pipe (see [pipe(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html)) or an `AF_UNIX` local [unix(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html) [socket(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/socket.2.html) (as commented by [caf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134633/caf)) at least to transmit control information -for synchronization- about the shared memory (i.e. tell when it has changed, that is when a message has been sent thru shared memory, etc.). Then you can still multiplex with e.g. [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or `ppoll(2)` or `pselect(2)` etc...)

I don't think that synchronization using signals is the right approach: signals are difficult to get right (so coding is tricky) and they are not more efficient than exchanging a few bytes on some pipe.

Did you consider to use [MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/)?

Comment: Agreed, except that you may need to use an `AF_UNIX` socket rather than a pipe if the processes don't have a parent/child relationship.

Comment: wasn't pselect designed to prevent the need of piped signal handlers? Is there a reason why a pipe assisted handler will be useful specifically with shared memory? It seems that it would negate the performance of the shared memory messages except in cases where large amounts of data is passed.

Comment: The pipe would transmit only control information for synchronization purposes (so you could `write(2)` & `read(2)` single byte control messages). The (big) data would be still shared memory. You need to synchronize somehow.

Comment: MPI is a great suggestion but I'm going to test pipes and sigqueues as useless suggested and likely use your method if there isn't a great performance difference

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to signal between processes rather than pass data, then an eventfd (see [eventfd(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/eventfd)) will allow you to use select() with less overhead than a pipe.  As with a pipe solution, the processes will require a parent/child relationship.

Comment: Can I write any 8 bit int value to an eventfd? For example, can I write a client id of sorts?

Comment: eventfd is used for signalling, not passing data as such.  It doesn't provide a queue of values, but a single value that can be written to and read from.  When you write a value to it, it will overwrite the existing value.  This is useful for counters and semaphores, but if you need FIFO behaviour then you should use a pipe or an other method.

Comment: If all you need is notification to check your shared memory, this should be fine though.

Answer (score 0):

I did some additional looking and came across [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html). I believe this will be the best solution - very similar to Basile Starynkevitch's suggestion but without the overhead of standard pipes and done within the kernel rather than userspace.

Answer (score -2):

pipe+select+queue+lock, nothing else.

Comment: Why not `poll` instead of `select` ?

Comment: I can think of plenty 'else'

Comment: this is a very inaccurate answer